# Как нарисовать треугольник в пайтоне через цикл?

Tags: python

Обучаюсь пайтону.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как нарисовать фигуру (треугольник) в пайтоне через цикл.
Не пойму как добавить в цикл доп.пробелы что бы было в 1 строке ' ' + текст, потом ' '' ' + текст и т.д

вот код

```
i = 18
d = '&'
s = 18
p = ' '
print(d * i)
while s != 9:
    s -= 1
    i -= 2
    print(p + (d * i))
```

Comment: Дайте больше информации: напишите полное условие задачи, приведите пример желаемого результата.

Comment: @MiniMax Нужно вывести треугольник из символов с помощью цикла
где в первой строке 26 символов и на уменьшение

Comment: А что не так с этим кодом?

Answer (score 1):

С минимальной переделкой, хотя код и не оптимальный совсем:

```
i = 18
d = '&'
s = 18
p = ' '
print(d * i)
while s != 9:
    s -= 1
    i -= 2
    print(p * (18-i) + (d * i)) # здесь добавил впереди пробелов
```

Результат:

```
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
    &&&&&&&&&&&&&&
      &&&&&&&&&&&&
        &&&&&&&&&&
          &&&&&&&&
            &&&&&&
              &&&&
                &&
```

Тоже самое можно сделать в пару строк в принципе. Вариант "конусом вниз":

```
n = 19
for i in range(0, n):
    print(' ' * i + '&' * (n - i * 2) + ' ' * i)

&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
 &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& 
  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&  
   &&&&&&&&&&&&&   
    &&&&&&&&&&&    
     &&&&&&&&&     
      &&&&&&&      
       &&&&&       
        &&&        
         &
```

Comment: Нужно что бы конусом вниз, что бы кол по середине был

Comment: @Alex Могли бы уже догадаться, но я добавил

Comment: а как можно отзеркалить вниз? в том же коде, что бы получилось 2 таких, одна вниз смотрит, а другая вверх

Comment: Ещё один цикл сделать, только в обратную сторону. Сделайте хоть что-то сами попробуйте