# Помогите с задачей, в описание

Tags: python, input

Нарисовать равнобедренный треугольник из символов *.Направлений вниз  Высоту выбирает пользователь.  Максимальная висота 15, минимальная 1  Например: высота = 5, на экране
P.S " - " считать за пробел

Comment: Вам понадобится цикл фор и формирование строки в зависимости от ее номера

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1106960/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB

Answer (score -2):

```
print("Введите высоту треугольника [1 -- 15]")
high = int(input())
space = 0

if 1 <= high <= 15:
    foot = 2 * high - 2

    for i in range(foot+2):
        print('*', end='')
    print()

    while foot > 0:
        space += 1
        for i in range(space):
            print(' ', end='')
        print('*', end='')
        foot -= 2
        for i in range(foot):
            print('+', end='')
        print('*', end='')
        print()
else:
    print("Это число не ноходится в диапозоне")
```

В print('+', end='') символ '+' можно поменять на ' '

Comment: Так строки умеете формировать: `'*'*7` ? И многовато всего накрутили, плюсики там вообще не нужны

Comment: Ваша правда, а вот до '*' * n я не догадался